# How can I make Unchained characters in PCGen?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoner, pathfinder-society, unchained, pcgen

I am making a character to be played in PFS by my friend, and they want to play a Summoner. Chained Summoners are not legal, but PCGen doesn't seem to support the Unchained one. Is there any way to actually do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It is possible, but it's complicated.

[Wrattsy's comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/5eg71b/anyone_know_how_to_make_an_unchained_character_in/dac9sjv/) on [this /r/Pathfinder_RPG post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/5eg71b/anyone_know_how_to_make_an_unchained_character_in/) has helped me to do it. Basically, you need to do the following. I've rewritten and expanded Wrattsy's instruction to make building Unchained characters easy.

1. Make sure you have an up-to-date version of PCGen.
2. Start it.
3. On start-up, when it asks you which sources to load, switch to the Advanced tab.
4. Type "Unchained" (or just "Unch") in the search bar.
5. Double click on "Pathfinder Unchained". It should be added to the bar on the right, along with any other sources you have.
6. Press "Load" and wait for the program to load.
7. Press "File" -- "New" to make a new character.
8. Go to the "Class" tab and take a level in the normal version of your desired class. For example, Summoner.
9. Go to the "Feats & Abilities" tab, choose the "Class Features" sub-tab.
10. Find your class on the list, aid yourself by using the search bar.
11. Click on it once. You will see two options in the bar below: "Favored Class" and "Summoner Class Selection" (replace "Summoner" with your chosen class here and below).
12. In the bar above, you will see "Unchained Summoner". Double-click on it to choose that option.
13. Save your character and close it. You don't have to exit PCGen, just close the character.
14. Open your character again. You can now build it normally.

Does this sound like an intuitive interface? Not to me.